# Socket - server does not receive client messages

Tags: java, sockets, p2p

I'm new in client/server programming so I tried to write a simple chat program peer-to-peer so each program has it's own client and server and the programs are directly connected something like this.

```
  Program1                   Program2
|----------|               |----------|
|--Client--|-------------->|--Server--|
|----------|  connections  |----------|
|--Server--|<--------------|--Client--|
|----------|               |----------|
```

The problem is that the servers and clients are connected but the messages simply don't reach the servers.

I followed line by line the code with the debugger and noticed that after the (correct) initialization of the server, when it reaches the second `writer.readLine()`, the debugger just stop following the code like the thread is waiting for something to happen and the loop that should get and print the messages simply doesn't run.
Server:

```
@Override
public void run() {
    try {
        // the following code is executed
        server = new ServerSocket(port);
        port = server.getLocalPort();
        logMessage("[Server]Server started.");
        logMessage("[Server]Server is waiting on port: " + this.port + ".");
        while(true) {
            logMessage("[Server]Waiting for connection...");
            client = server.accept();
            logMessage("[Server]Client connecting on port: " + port + ".");
            logMessage("[Server]Client ip: " + client.getInetAddress());
            requestConnection(); // Here I ask the user if he want to accept the client or disconnect
            try {
                synchronized(this) {
                    this.wait(); // Waiting for the user responce...
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            // When the user write the answer the thread wake up!
            PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(client.getOutputStream()));
            if(!connectionAccepted.toUpperCase().equals("Y")) {
                writer.println(Connection.REFUSED.ordinal());
                writer.flush();
                writer.close();
                client.close();
                System.out.println("Connection refused.");
                continue;
            }

            writer.println(Connection.ACCEPTED.ordinal());
            writer.flush();
            System.out.println("Connection accepted.");

            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream()));
            message = reader.readLine(); // This code get the port where the client of this program has to connect to
            GUI.connect(client.getInetAddress().getHostName(), Integer.parseInt(message));
            message = reader.readLine(); // Here is where the debug stop

            while(!message.equals("/disconnect")) {
                if(message != null)
                    logMessage(message);
                message = reader.readLine();
                System.out.println("Waiting for message..."); // This method should be called several times but in the console there is no message
            }
            client.close();
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        logStackTrace(e);
    }
}
```

Client:

```
@Override
public void run() {
    try {
        client = new Socket(host, port);

        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream()));
        String message = reader.readLine();
        logMessage("[Client]Message recieved: " + message);
        try {
            if(Integer.parseInt(message) == Connection.ACCEPTED.ordinal()) {
                logMessage("[Client]Connection accepted.");
            } else {
                logMessage("[Client]Connection refused.");
            }
        } catch(NumberFormatException e) {
            logStackTrace(e);
            reader.close();
        }
        writer = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(client.getOutputStream()));
        writer.println(GUI.getServer().getPort());
        writer.flush();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        logStackTrace(e);
    }
}
```

"Send" method of the client:

```
public void send(String message) {
    writer.println(message);
    writer.flush();
}
```

Comment: Well in your client you are only `println()` one thing and so the server would hang there waiting for input from the client

Comment: I haven't written the GUI code (because I use javafx for the user interface) but in there when the user write something and click enter then is called the send method of the client with the message. @3kings

Comment: It most likely is hanging on somewhere at input needed from the client. You should easily tell where it hangs by debugging a little more.

Comment: I'm tring to debug also the source code of the BufferedReader class in the jre but I can't figure out why the thread stops running.